# Differences in custom and std fetch_add on floats

Tags: c++, gcc, assembly, x86-64

This is an attempt at implementing `fetch_add` on floats without C++20.

```
void fetch_add(volatile float* x, float y)
{
    bool success = false;
    auto xi = (volatile std::int32_t*)x;
    while(!success)
    {
        union {
            std::int32_t sumint;
            float sum;
        };
        auto tmp = __atomic_load_n(xi, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
        sumint = tmp;
        sum += y;
        success = __atomic_compare_exchange_n(xi, &tmp, sumint, true, __ATOMIC_RELAXED, __ATOMIC_RELAXED);
    }
}
```

To my great confusion, when I compare [the assembly](https://godbolt.org/z/uIW92y) from gcc10.1 `-O2  -std=c++2a` for x86-64, they differ.

```
fetch_add(float volatile*, float):
.L2:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        movd    xmm1, eax
        addss   xmm1, xmm0
        movd    edx, xmm1
        lock cmpxchg    DWORD PTR [rdi], edx
        jne     .L2
        ret
fetch_add_std(std::atomic<float>&, float):
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rdi]
        movaps  xmm1, xmm0
        movd    xmm0, eax
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-4], eax
        addss   xmm0, xmm1
.L9:
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rsp-4]
        movd    edx, xmm0
        lock cmpxchg    DWORD PTR [rdi], edx
        je      .L6
        mov     DWORD PTR [rsp-4], eax
        movss   xmm0, DWORD PTR [rsp-4]
        addss   xmm0, xmm1
        jmp     .L9
.L6:
        ret
```

My ability to read assembly is near non-existent, but the custom version looks correct to me, which implies it is either incorrect, inefficient or somehow the standard library is rather broken. I don't quite believe the third case, which leads me to ask, is the custom version incorrect or inefficient?

---

After some comments, [a second version](https://godbolt.org/z/oLGgvJ) without reloading after `cmpxchg` is written. They do still differ.

Comment: `auto xi = (volatile std::int32_t*)x;` is undefined behaviour (see https://gist.github.com/shafik/848ae25ee209f698763cffee272a58f8#catching-strict-aliasing-violations). I haven't had a look at the assembly.

Comment: @MutableSideEffect It's hard to talk about UB in the context of compiler intrinsics. [gcc](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/_005f_005fatomic-Builtins.html) says the intrinsic works on any data type, and I'm going off of that.

Comment: The standard version does the gpr<->xmm transfer through memory. Don't think that's better than `movd` which is used by the custom version (and is compiler generated there too). If the `cmpxchg` fails it does return the current value so you don't need to reload it - that's better in the standard version which makes use of this if only it didn't write it back out to the stack... Also it would be better to directly load into xmm but I guess the  `__atomic_load_n` doesn't take a float. On x86 a simple aligned load is atomic too, so if you only care about x86 you could use a simple C dereference.

Comment: Note also that the two functions implement different algorithms. Your version goes back and re-fetches the source value at each iteration. The standard version uses the result of the failed exchange as the starting point for the second and subsequent iterations.

Comment: @PasserBy: `(float&)tmp` is definitely strict-aliasing UB.  Some GCC versions choose to do what you mean, but seriously use a union or memcpy to type-pun an int to a float bit-pattern because GNU C/C++ defines the behaviour of both of those.  (Union type punning is UB in ISO C++ but GNU defines it as an extension)

Comment: @PeterCordes Well noted. I edited the original code snippet, but the output assembly is identical, hopefully not being too much of a problem.

Comment: Right, as I said this version of GCC isn't totally naive wrt. strict aliasing violations and will do what you want in some cases when it can see what you probably meant.  I didn't expect any change to the asm.  It's unfortunate that `(float&)` for type-punning is only well-defined on MSVC; other ways are clunky to write.

Comment: And BTW, it's the library version that compiles inefficiently; your version avoids the missed optimization of going through memory for int<->FP data movement without conversion.